# how to configure postgresql with play framework application

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.1, configure

I want to connect postgresql with play framework application. please any one help me to configure. what i should do in application.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a data source:

```
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql:database_name
```

References:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/configuration